# tableau custom sort x axis value

Tags: tableau-api

I have columnar stack bar chart and I want the values in x axis to be sorted by preference rather than automatic sort. Refer the image . I want the lower (ref image)[image] to come to first position and then 6 , 7 , 8 etc

Answer (score 0):

Simply drag and drop (pick from its name on axis) should work.  It works fine for me.